# Cannot execute job that runs a shell script

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, jobs, oracle-sql-developer

I have the following `pl/sql` script that should execute the shell script `script.sh`. When I runt the code below In SQLDeveloper I get:

```
    Error report -
ORA-27370: job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:accessing login executable failed with status: 2
ORA-27301: OS failure message: No such file or directory
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sjseccel 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 185
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 486
ORA-06512: at line 20
27370. 00000 -  "job slave failed to launch a job of type EXECUTABLE"
*Cause:    The scheduler ran into an error when the job slave tried to start
           a job of type EXECUTABLE. The rest of the error stack will provide
           more detailed information on what the exact problem was.
*Action:   Correct the problem specified in the error stack and reschedule
           the job.
```

The file exists and has the correct permissions on my system. Is something that I am doing wrong? Also, the provided credentials seem to be the correct ones.

An here is the code:

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_credential(
        credential_name => 'user_cred',
        username        => 'user',
        password        => 'pass');  
END;   
/

begin
      DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name           => 'test_prog',
         job_type           => 'EXECUTABLE',
        job_action         => '/home/user/Desktop/foo/script.sh',
         enabled            => TRUE,
         credential_name => 'user_cred'
      );
    dbms_scheduler.run_job('test_prog');
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like external scheduler jobs are not available in the XE edition.

Comment: why do you think so?

Comment: On my system, ubuntu 17.04, oracle needs to check the credentials provided before executing the job. In order to do this, it needs to use an executable, jssu, which is not present on my XE installation, but appears to exist in the EE installation. Am I wrong?

Comment: for Oracle 11.2 EE  I found $ORACLE_HOME/bin/jssu